# IBM MQ - How to independently dequeue a message and commit?

Tags: ibm-mq

My application has multiple servers connecting to MQ. So we have a separate wrapper service instance which interacts with MQ (MQ Put and Listeners for each queue).

In one of the scenarios, I have to manually dequeue a specific message based on the correlation id. In this case my application server is trying to call a wrapper MQ_APP_Get service. This MQ_APP_Get service, does a MQ Get based on the correlation id and commits the message so that it is deleted from the queue.
In the above case, there is a possibility that after MQ_APP_Get returns back the application message (it has already dequeued and deleted the message from queue), the original client application crashes. This might cause the message to be lost.
Is there any better way to handle this  message lost scenario ?

Comment: Since you mention about "commit", I am assuming your getting messages under a SYNC_POINT. In that case if commit is successful, then message is removed from the queue. If the application crashes beofre commit is called, queue manager will rollback the message, so message won't be lost.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking us how to change your MQ_APP_Get wrapper service so that it doesn't commit the message until later when you tell it to? If this is the case, you will need to show us the code. Alternatively, you could write the MQGET yourself instead of using the wrapper, and then when you are finished with the message, write the MQCMIT yourself. This way the message won't be lost as if your application crashed before it does the MQCMIT the message will be rolled back. For further help, you will need to tell us more about your application, e.g. what language it is written in.

Comment: @MoragHughson You are right in your understanding. My applicaiton itself could call MQGET and do MQCMIT once done.  But the only problem is my application does not have direct connectivity to MQ by itself.  It is abstracted to a different layer which is in MQ_APP_GET service. The code is in C++

Comment: It sounds like whoever wrote the code for "MQ_APP_Get wrapper service" (and probably MQ_APP_Put wrapper service) broke the most basic rule of providing service: the service should ONLY do 1 thing.  But in your case, it is doing 2 things: MQGET and MQCMIT.  Tell whoever wrote the code, break the code into individual components.  i.e. MQ_APP_Get and MQ_APP_Commit services.  When writing a middleware service (or micro service), the service should be doing exactly 1 thing and not a variety of things.